# set default value checkbox android

Tags: android, checkbox

i have data in database with value from checkbox
i try to set checkbox with value from database, if database not null checkbox checked but if null checkbox not checked..
my code like this:

```
public void load(){
   final Cursor c = helper.getSat(almagId);
       c.moveToFirst();
   if(c.getString(3) != null){
           ch1.isChecked();
   }
   isi2.setText(c.getString(4));
   if(c.getString(4) != null){
       ch2.isChecked();
   }
   isi3.setText(c.getString(5));
   if(c.getString(5) != null){
       ch3.isChecked();
   }
}
```

but it's not work..how can i solve this??thank you for feed back :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`isChecked()` will tell you if the `CheckBox` is checked or not; you cannot change the 'checked' value with this method.

In order to change it, use either [`setChecked(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setChecked%28boolean%29) for an explicit value or [`toggle()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#toggle%28%29) to inverse it.

Answer (score 0):

isChecked doesn't set the checkbox, it just tells you whether or not it's already checked.  In order to set the checkbox to checked, call setChecked(boolean check), like this:

```
checkBox.setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure the DB is returning nulls in the cursor (as opposed to empty strings)?

You haven't said how it's not working (all checked or none checked or wrong ones checked, so the above is a best guess stab in the dark).